# Plotting data and functions in C++

Tags: c++, plot, gnuplot

I am a beginner to programming and I have to generate and plot certain recursions such as `x(n+1)=a*x(n)+b*x(n)^2`.

I am supposed to use only C/C++ and not mathematical software such as MATLAB, GNU Octave, etc. I am however allowed to use `Gnuplot`.

Can you tell me what is the best way in which I can arrive at the plots for the above recursions and how I can implement it in my code? Is generating the values, storing it in a file using fstream, and then plotting it later a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Boost Visualizer Library

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html

Or go for OGDF using GML output, fairly straightforward

http://www.ogdf.net/ogdf.php?id=

These are all C++ Libraries, not 3rd party software like MATLAB.

Comment: @Meghdeep Ray the referred boost link is about algorithms for graph-theoretic problems, not general plotting and graphing of data.